# Make column as dictionary key and row as value in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have Dataframe as below.

```
name    value     id
A       123         1
B       345         5
C       567         4
D       789         2
```

I need to create a dictionary of the form below

```
{
  {"name":"A",
   "value":123,
   "id":1
  },
  {"name":"B",
   "value":345,
   "id":5
  },
  {"name":"C",
   "value":567,
   "id":4
  },
  {"name":"D",
   "value":789,
   "id":2
  }
}
```

I tried below code, but it makes 'name' as the key.

```
data_set.set_index('name').to_dict(orient='list')
```

How to get the dictionary of the form i have mention? Do i need to iterate through rows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this:

```
data_set.to_dict(orient = 'records')
```

Comment: Thank you. this is exactly what i needed